# How to make this I2C OLED screen work? (probably SH1106)

Tags: arduino, led, i2c, oled

I have just received this screen: [link](https://www.banggood.com/0_96-Inch-I2C-IIC-SPI-Serial-128-x-64-OLED-LCD-LED-Display-Module-p-922246.html) but unfortunately it's different then other showed in reviews. That's my version [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3I4mr.jpg)

It's probably based on SH1106 but I can't make it work. I have tried few popular Arduino libraries but I can't get address of this screen from I2C scanner - it's not answering.

Anyone knows how to program it?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that your OLED screen might be a SSD1306 based one, and not a SH1106 as you believe.

Should that be the case, I think you'll be glad to know that there is a library for it (made by Adafruit):

https://learn.adafruit.com/monochrome-oled-breakouts/arduino-library-and-examples

From what I've read, you should also do a small code modification in order to get your OLED display working. It's simple and you can find it here:

http://www.modlog.net/?p=887

Hope this helps you out.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I have tried both libraries: Adafruit and U8glib. Also I have tried both drivers.
I'm connecting SCL to PIN3, SDA to PIN2 of my Leonardo. RST to 5V and D/C to GND. And of course I have tried different settings and combination. Sometimes without connected one of data cables display is showing random noise but after restarting it's black again.

Comment: Hmmm, that's strange. Many google results pointed out that your display should be SSD1306. You haven't provided a schematic or a guide which shows your connections. Can you provide us with a link or image that showsthem? 
You are using pull-up resistors on the I2C lines, right?
(more on that matter: http://www.dsscircuits.com/index.php/articles/47-effects-of-varying-i2c-pull-up-resistors)

Comment: Excuse me this weak hand drawing, I'm only on iPad now: [schematic](http://i.imgur.com/twZcZ7D.jpg)

Comment: The Arduino Leonardo is (I suppose) working at 5V level (and I believe you power the OLED display from the 5V rail of the Arduino). While the technical info on the product page states that it can be powered between 3V and 5V, it should be working at 3.3V logic levels, while you're pulling it up to 5V. The OLED controller might not be satisfied with that and refuse to work, or, in worst case scenario, is already damaged. (at least the SSD1306 datasheet states that its' logic works between 1.65V and 3.3V and doesn't mention it being 5V tolerant. https://www.adafruit.com/datasheets/SSD1306.pdf)

Comment: I will try with voltage shifter when it will arrive (or I will make one), thank you for all answers! And yes, it's probably already damaged...

Comment: This is probably a bit offtopic, but they were the ones that sent you the wrong module. Granted, you could still have damaged your OLED display even if they had sent you the right one, but in the end you can argue that you have the wrong, non fitting part and they will refund you (I buy on that website, they seem to be honest). I advise you to try that. Should you want to build a level shifter, I suggest you this link http://husstechlabs.com/support/tutorials/bi-directional-level-shifter/ If you don't have 2N7000 MOSFET you can probably replace them.

Answer (score 1):

I could make the display work with the Adafruit library, based on the configuration as follows:

```
// If using software SPI (the default case):
#define OLED_MOSI   11       //SDA in the OLED display
#define OLED_CLK   13        //SCL in the OLED display
#define OLED_DC    9         //D/C in the OLED display
#define OLED_CS    10        //Its not connected
#define OLED_RESET 2         //RST in the OLED display
Adafruit_SSD1306 display(OLED_MOSI, OLED_CLK, OLED_DC, OLED_RESET, OLED_CS);
```

Remember: Use the example with the SPI communication, evertything works GREAT!!

Comment: This looks like maybe it should be an edit to your other answer? You can edit your answers at any stage to add additional information and normally the only time to post multiple answers on Stack Exchange sites is if they are two different ways to solve the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I just bought a display exactly like yours and had also the same problem... and trying to find a solution I came with your question, and later I found the solution!!:

http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=217290.0

Follow the steps from the user: Caltoa, -Use the U8glib, take the 'Hello World' example for Arduino, and uncomment the section:

```
U8GLIB_SSD1306_128X64 u8g(13, 11, 10, 9);   // SW SPI Com: SCK = 13, MOSI = 11, CS = 10, A0 = 9
```

And add a '2' at the end, like this:

```
U8GLIB_SSD1306_128X64 u8g(13, 11, 10, 9, 2);    // SW SPI Com: SCK = 13, MOSI = 11, CS = 10, A0 = 9
```

Then connect like this:

```
U8GLIB_SSD1306_128X64 u8g( SCL, SDA, 'cs no connected', D/C, RST);
```

Totally Working!!

p.s. 
It is not an I2C display, it uses a SPI communication, the labels on the display are wrong! That is why in the library you have to use the 'Software SPI Communication'.

Hope it works with you, and everyone with the same problem!!

Comment: First, you put an example with a string as a char (single quote instead of double quote) and a compile error: 'D' was not declared in this scope. "Totally Working!" ..... nope, sorry.